# Asynchronous URLRequest data task times out

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurlsession, xctest, xctestexpectation

Attempting to get the following test working. It never enters the completion block and instead it times out after 30 seconds. The request seems like it is never made, as I can't see it on Charles.

```
func testAsynchronousURLConnection() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")!
    let exp = expectation(description: "Async request")

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        XCTAssertNotNil(data, "data should not be nil")
        XCTAssertNil(error, "error should be nil")
        exp.fulfill()
    }

   task.resume()

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 30) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

The test fails with the error:

> *Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 30 seconds with unfulfilled expectations: "Async request"*

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you take Charles out of the equation, do you see the same behavior? I wonder if there's something strange in the SSL Proxy settings (e.g. waiting for some confirmation of the certificate or something weird like that). Having said that, I'd still expect it to succeed or fail immediately. I'm using Charles to watch this and it works fine...

Comment: Yeah, I just closed Charles and created a new project. Copy and pasted the test over, it works there, but not in my existing project. Absolutely confused as to what my existing project may contain that blocks it.